# Where can I find a copy of Demazure and Gabriel's Introduction to algebraic geometry and algebraic groups

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, soft-question

The question is pretty self explanatory. The book has been checked out of my university library, and I checked Amazon, and it says that the book is out of print. Also, I do not know French, so I am specifically looking for the English version. In a situation like this, I do not really mind downloading an online copy, if there is a link that works (I have searched online, but could not find an online copy of this book. Google books has a preview of this book, but, as usual, with pages missing).

Comment: The book is available at library.nu. I don't know if this sort of comment is allowed on math.SE... If it isn't, then let it be erased (I'll just hope the OP will have read it by then :) )

Comment: The English translation only covers half the material and has vastly inferior typesetting. Anyway, I think you must be looking in the wrong places if you can't find a copy online. ;)

Comment: @ZhenLin: Well, would be be so kind as to point me in the right direction then?

Comment: @BrunoStonek: I don't understand how library.nu works. It seems you need to log in, but there is no place for registering on the site. All I see is a short clip from The Simpsons...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sale as an e-book at 
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/bookseries/03040208/39

Comment: Is there a place on the page where I can buy the e-book? The individual chapters have only one page abstracts.

Comment: I see a link which says 'Purchase' in the gray bar at the top of the individual chapters.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, I could not find the link you mention. Perhaps you have some sort of access that I don't.

Comment: I just have access to the first page previews of each chapter.